# loop nested object react native

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native and want to loop trough a nested object. I created a file named 'spots.js' i looks like this:

```
export {spots};

var spots = [
  {
    name: 'Barberistas',
    location: 'Geleen',
    img_url: require('../assets/snipes/coffeesnipe-barberistas.jpg'),
    isFavourite: false,
    imagesReviews:{
      img1: require('../assets/snipes/coffeesnipe-barberistas.jpg'),
      img2: require('../assets/snipes/coffeesnipe-barberistas.jpg'),
      img3: require('../assets/snipes/coffeesnipe-barberistas.jpg'),
    }
  },
]
```

Now i'm trying to show the images from 'spots' of imagesReviews. I know how i loop trough a object but i'm stucked with this nested object. At the moment i have this:

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true}> 
  {
    spots.map((l) => {
      return <Image source={ l.imagesReviews }></Image>

    })
  } 
</ScrollView>
```

Screenshot of structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwl5z.png)

Is there someone who can help me show those pictures in this scrollview? I imported everything the correct way, my only question is how can i loop trough that nested object and only show the imagesReviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate over inner object.

You can do this,

```
{
  spots.map((l) => {
    //It might be possible that not every object in spots array has imagesReviews object. 
    //Just put a check that every node in spots array contains imagesReviews object and then only show Image

    if(l.imagesReviews){
       return Object.keys(l.imagesReviews).map(key => <Image source={ l.imagesReviews[key] }></Image>)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! When i do this i get ' TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(l.imagesReviews)')

Comment: How you are importing `spots`?

Comment: import {spots} from '../spots/spots';

Comment: Try `console.log(l.imagesReviews)` and check you are getting object.

Comment: I get a error when i try console log: 'typeError: cannot convert undefined or null to object'

Comment: I think you are not getting `spots` array, try to check if you are getting data, `console.log(spots)`.

Comment: nope i get nothing, is there something wrong in my import method?

Comment: Can you post your folder structure? You import path is wrong.

Comment: i changed the structure and import to the right way but still gettin this error

Comment: If you are still not getting the value of `spots`, it means your import path is still wrong. Can't you update your post with your folder structure? You can just take a screenshot and post here.

Comment: I have added the screen shot at the moment i import it like this: 'import {spots} from './spots/spots';'

Comment: In which file you are importing `spots`?

Comment: coffeeloversScreen.js

Comment: This import `import {spots} from './spots/spots';` is correct. Now are you getting `spots` array after `console.log(spots)`?

Comment: nope stil getting the error: 'TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object'

Comment: @JoppeMeijers, I got your issue, It might be possible that not every object in `spots` array has `imagesReviews` object. You just need to add a `if` condition. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Yes this is the solution! Thanks for your help!